# Change PNG image color by PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, image, png

It is possible that I can change the image color of png image by php/js functions?

I would like to change color only on non-transparent area. An example image is available here:

[image]

I would like to change colors only on the visible t-shirt not on all area.

Comment: You can position a `<div>` on top of the image and color its background. You can also use `<canvas>` drawing, or create an image on the fly with PHP image commands. Bottom line is, you're posting here way too early.

Comment: I'm using this image in canvas composition. I don't want to change the background of the tranasparent area, but only the visible part of the image. How can I achieve this by PHP? I think that i have to calculate where the transparent area is visible, and fill with color everything what is not transparent. Could you tell me which PHP methods are available to do this?

Comment: To color the opaque pixels, you can use the `imageData` object of a `<canvas>` context. The data is a huge array, with each group of four values representing one pixel's R, G, B and A channels. Use the A channel to determine opaqueness, then change RGB according to the color. Again, SO isn't a "how do I do X?" site. You're supposed to do the research, implement a solution, then ask a question when you get really, really stuck.

Comment: Please post the actual transparent png, not one with a checkerboard pattern in its place.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for the response. Here is a transparent png: https://imgur.com/9TxcJbj It is possible to change color only of presented tshirt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your actual transparent PNG input file. In lieu of that, in ImageMagick command line, this I think should work to colorize the white to sky-blue.

```
convert image.png \
\( -clone 0 -alpha off -fill skyblue -colorize 100 \) \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract \) \
-compose multiply -composite \
result.png
```

I do not know PHP Imagick that well. So I will leave my answer to someone to translate to Imagick.

Comment: The result of that command is resolving my problem, but I have to figure out how to achieve same result by PHP Imagick methods. Thank you.

Comment: The first parenthesis is like colorizeImage at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.colorizeimage.php. The second parenthesis is like separateImageChannel at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.separateimagechannel.php using the alpha channel. The compose multiply is like compositeImage at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP imagick library. I think it's the best way.

[Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)

For example :

```
<?php

$imageInPath = __DIR__. '\\image-before.png';
$imageOutPath = __DIR__. '\\image-after.png';

$overlayColor = '#F00'; // Red for example
$fuzz = 0;

$overlay = new Imagick( $imageInPath ); // Create imagick object
$overlay->opaquePaintImage ( $overlay->getImagePixelColor(0, 0) , $overlayColor , $fuzz , true ); // Fill the opaque area

$image = new Imagick($imageInPath); // Create imagick object
$image->compositeImage($overlay, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DARKEN  , 0, 0); // Compose the original image with the overlay
$image->writeImage( $imageOutPath ); // Save the image to the given path

?>
```

This snippet assumes that the first pixel (x=0, y=0) is transparent.

You can change the way to apply the overlay on the picture by using another COMPOSITE constant. You can get the full list of imagick constants here : [Imagick constants](http://php.net/manual/fr/imagick.constants.php)

Don't forget to install Imagick library and to enable it in the php.ini file to get it work.

Comment: Could you provide reasons as to why you think the Imagick class is the best way to proceed? Maybe a small example to illustrate how you would achieve what the OP is looking for advice on? Thanks!

Comment: I just added an example to my post.

Comment: I think it's the best way because the client-side implementation is not supported by all browsers yet, and the command line solution with ImageMagick need to use the awful exec() function.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick could be a good route to take (check out [PHP.net's Imagick reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), and [phpimagick.com](http://phpimagick.com/)), as it'll do the operation on the server, and 'theoretically' work no matter what, (e.g., even if the client's JS is turned off).

If you're not able to use it (e.g., your hosting's limited), an option via JavaScript is to use an offscreen canvas, draw the images to it, generate a PNG from it, and then finally add it to the page.

Here's an example of some working code:

```
// shirtPath: the url to the shirt
// overlayPath: the url to the overlay image
// callback: a callback that is given the image once it's generated
function generateShirtOverlay(shirtPath,overlayPath,callback) {
    // load the images
    var loadedImages = 0;
    function imageLoaded() {
        loadedImages++;
        if(loadedImages == 2) {
            composeImages();
        }
    }
    var shirtImage = new Image(),
        overlayImage = new Image();
    // set the image onload callbacks
    shirtImage.onload = imageLoaded;
    overlayImage.onload = imageLoaded;
    // load the images
    shirtImage.src = shirtPath;
    overlayImage.src = overlayPath;

    var generatedImage = new Image();
    function composeImages() {
        // get image sizes
        var width = shirtImage.width,
            height = shirtImage.height,
            overlayWidth = overlayImage.width,
            overlayHeight = overlayImage.height;

        // create a canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        // draw the shirt to it
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(shirtImage,0,0);

        // set the global composite operator to multiply
        // this overlays the image nicely, keeping the
        // dark areas on the shirt dark
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
        // draw the overlay image, centering it if it's
        // not the same size
        context.drawImage(overlayImage,
                    (width - overlayWidth) / 2,
                    (height - overlayHeight) / 2
                );

        // a bit of masking magic! for details, see:
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
        // draw the shirt again; this clips the overlay image
        // at the shirt's edges
        context.drawImage(shirtImage,0,0);

        // finally, extract a PNG from the canvas
        var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        generatedImage.onload = returnComposedImage();
        // and load it to an image object
        generatedImage.src = png;
    }

    function returnComposedImage() {
        if(typeof callback == "function")
            callback(generatedImage);
    }
}
```

This function could be called to generate the image. Ultimately, it'll call a callback, providing the generated image. Then, since it's an Image object, you can add it right to the page, e.g.:

```
function addImageToPage(image) {
    document.body.appendChild(image);
}
generateShirtOverlay("images/shirt.png", "images/design1.png", addImageToPage);
```

Please note, though, the disadvantage of client-side rendering is that not all browsers support all these canvas features. In addition, it's a little more overhead on the client-side. Fortunately, though, as it's not an extremely complex manipulation, this method uses only image blend modes, and doesn't need to iterate pixels.